# how to handle non responsive UI while downloading from NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

after looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725911/how-can-i-download-a-pdf-document-from-the-web-to-my-iphone-apps-document-folder), I do not know how to handle non responsive UI while writing a large pdf file (on 3G connection let's say) from a remote server to the documents directory, is there way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch,an NSOperation or an asynchronous NSURLConnection request

All are well explained in the Apple docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the download on a background thread using [`performSelectorInBackground`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).